# Oracle Apex 19.1 Class chart 100% width of region

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a classic report that is inside a tabbed region and I would like the classic report to be 100% of the width available. It is current stopping about halfway or so. I have tried every combination of settings I can find and nothing seems to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image: Classic chart only taking up part of the tab]

[image: Page editor view of the classic report]

Many thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 3):

in report attribute go to template option and check the stretch report option

Comment: Thank thank thank! I had found the option in the report but not attribute. You a rock!